# What is the exact value of the series $\sqrt{1+2\times\sqrt{1+3\times\sqrt{1+4\times\sqrt\cdot.....}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, nested-radicals

Kindly tell me
what is the value of:

$\sqrt{1+2\times\sqrt{1+3\times\sqrt{1+4\times\sqrt\cdot.....}}}$

According to ramanujan ,it is equal to 3

I want to know how...

Comment: You should be using backward slashes, \, instead of forward slashes, /, to format your question.

Comment: In third line it is 3,,, not 3!=6,,,

Comment: What might help : If we replace the square root after the number $n$ with $n+2$ , we get exactly $3$, for example $$\sqrt{1+2\cdot \sqrt{1+3\cdot \sqrt{1+4\cdot 6}}}=3$$

Comment: I've seen ramanujan's solutions but I am not satisfied that this will work up to infinity....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula makes no sense. When u write "$\ldots$" it's like  saying "and so on" where you expect the reader to understand from context what you are talking about.

For example if commonly when u see $1+2+3+4+\ldots$ you would think about a limit of sequence of partial sums therefore you would said $1+2+3+4+\ldots=\infty$ since that sequence does not converge.

However, speaking of ramanujan, he used different context where he stated that $1+2+3+4+\ldots=-{1 \over 12}$ simply because he meant something different by "$\ldots$"

Returning to your question. Your "$\ldots$" does not point to any scheme.
ramanujan wrote something like it's 3 because

$3=\sqrt{9}=\sqrt{1+2\cdot4}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{16}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\cdot5}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{25}}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\cdot6}}}=\ldots=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{\ldots}}}}$

Unfortunately such argument would work for any positive value.

For example $10=\sqrt{100}=\sqrt{1+2\cdot{99 \over 2}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\cdot{                              9797 \over 12}}}=\ldots$

the weird fraction will become irrelevant